# Programmatically 'unselect' a jQuery UI selectable widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

Is there a way to programmatically 'unselect' any and all selected elements for a given `$("#selectable").selectable()` widget?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following command works at http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/

```
$('#selectable .ui-selected').removeClass('ui-selected')
```

Since a class's existence defines if an item is selected, simply removing the item will deselect it.

Note, you can also take advantage of toggleClass and addClass functions.

EDIT:

Try this too: `$('#selectable').trigger('unselected')`. That might also trigger all the css changes as well, and this way the unselected event also gets triggered for whatever else may be hooked to it.

Comment: by this way, seem it does not raise "unselected" event :(

Comment: I think the proper way with latest jquery-ui is, $('#selectable').data("ui-selectable")._mouseStop(null);

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer only unselects visually. It doesn't trigger the *unselected* callback.

This can be used instead:

```
$(".ui-selected").each(function(i,e){
  $(".selector").selectable("triggerunselect",e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could destroy and reinit the current "selectable" instance.

For instance like this:

```
$("#selectable-area").selectable("destroy");
```

then

```
$("#selectable-area").selectable();
```